# How to filter non kernel(User imported) dll's from DIA SDK?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pdb-files, dbghelp, dia-sdk

I need to specifically filter all user imported dll's. DIA SDK gives all modules under SymTagCompiland which includes all kernel and other imports those are not explicitly linked.

I only need those dependent Dll's(modules) which are explicitly linked at runtime or at compile time(mentioned in Linker's Input area of project Configuration).

How can I filter this?

Regards,
Usman

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need DIA for that? You can use `EnumProcessModules` if process is loaded.

Or you can look into PE itself. [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985992.aspx) explains it.

You may need to hook into `LoadLibrary` and/or `DllMain` to get if some DLL is dynamically loaded.  Check [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/APIHooking.aspx) for hooking.

Unless you are writing a debugger, DIA or `WaitForDebugEvent`-`ContinueDebugEvent` is not required.